# NCover free Version for multiple solutions

Tags: c#, nunit, ncover

I am using NCover 1.5.8 which comes with TestDriven.Net 3.0. I am using NCover for Visual studio 10.0.

I have 26 Solutions and each solution having about 10-30 projects total is about 560 projects. I use a common directory for building all solutions.

When I am running NCover for a single file or for a project or even for a complete solution then it's working fine but **I am unable to run NCover for all the 26 solutions at a time.**

All the 26 solutions belongs to a single software product and many projects having cross solution DLL reference so I need coverage according to that. I have also tried to run it using console but in case of console I am getting empty coverage XML file.

I am using NUnit 2.5.10, NCover 1.5.8, TestDriven.Net 3.0, Visual Studio 2010 professional, Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: @Bankateshvar Narayan: Please elaborate your question. How is it possible to have 26 solutions for a product? 
All these 560 projects are of executable type ? If not, no need to add that project, if you have selected that project as a reference to main application.

Comment: Actually it is a Windows application which does a lot of data processing & conversion. It has 8 exe files and hundreds of DLLs.But I cannot use exe for coverage. We never use exe at our local development machine. So I want to use code coverage tool at Visual studio .NET source code or at the location where all dll files are. I have written my own build script and so all dll & exe file exists in a single folder. So I will be happy if any Code coverage tool works for all these files and generate a single report.